# Version Control tightly integrated into the Platform - is this coming?

Tags: isv, partner, release, versioning, version-control

Besides my disappointment that this years Dreamforce did not bring any notable improvements for isv and partners that mainly use the platform, I stumbled over this screenshot in [this Platform EBook (Slide37)](https://secure2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/Salesforce1-Platform-Services-ebook.pdf).

[image]

It looks like a feature-by-feature version control tightly integrated into Salesforce.com. I can't believe that they jus made-up this screen without working on something in the background.

Do you know what we see here?

Comment: that sure looks promising....!

Comment: Where in the documentation did you find this?  It just looks like a mock page, but is still very exciting.

Comment: @ThomasCrouse: I updated the text above with a link to this document.

Comment: We did get a demo of interactive debugging at DF14, so i'm pretty pleased with that, but this looks very interesting, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Another good sign that something with Versioning is "in the making" is the " Version Control Init Org Repo" Background Job Type. Just found it in my org ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This feature is going to go into pilot in Winter or Spring '15.  Note this idea being "Under Consideration" https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrBKAA0.

Comment: Wow, 7 years in the making.....

Comment: I heard it mentioned as being in development at several sessions this year, but I didn't hear anyone commit to a particular release...but it did sound like we would see something concrete in 2015

Comment: @Phil Rymek How can we get pilot program in DE org?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I think this all comes under the Umbrella name **Salesforce.com Agile Accelerator** which was announced in the [Partner keynote on Dreamforce '14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ut56sW7RHxk&t=81m33s). Salesforce.com seems to soon release it's internal development and planning tools GUS (http://youtu.be/GR2RRyqIdvo) as an AppExchange app to its partners.